# Conditional compilation for a module inside lib/

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is it possible to exclude/add a module which exists inside lib/ folder for a specific env?

```
defp elixirc_paths(:prod), do: ["lib", "lib/only-prod-module]
defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib"]
```

Looks like is being added also to the rest of the environments because it exists inside lib, can it be excluded somehow without having to add it outside lib module?

Comment: What is your use case for something like this? You could just wrap your module definition in an `if Mix.env() == :prod do ... end` and it will only get compiled for the `:prod` env. But in my experience this is not actually the solution you want.

Comment: Just curious if you can exclude paths or add some kind of regex on elixirc_path, not really using this approach for any use case right now, also for example I could just use defp elixirc_paths(:prod), do: ["lib", "prod/only-prod-module] but that would mean to define a different path

Comment: @JustinWood but that doesn't look maintainable, does it? It seems easier to just point and compile entire files or folders for a given environment.

Comment: @Sebastialonso I say right in my comment that it is generally not what you want to do. I asked for the usecase so that I could try to come up with a better solution. Basically, I think this is an example of the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @JustinWood One use-case I'm considering is some 'configuration management' code, e.g. creating and managing VPS instances for my project (in several 'production' environments). I don't need or want that code in the actual `:prod` environment app code and would run that code in `iex` via `MIX_ENV=ops iex -S mix` exclusively.

Comment: Then use the provided `elixirc_paths` to include a different directory for your `ops` environment.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally*, you should strongly prefer to use configuration to account for differences in your
project's environments.

But one category of (possibly) reasonable use-cases would be for (relatively) ad-hoc Elixir
'script code' for your project. I'm considering doing something like what is outlined in the
question for some (vaguely) 'configuration management' code for a project that's written in Elixir
and uses other application code and configuration. The code would be called via `iex` using a
special `Mix` environment, e.g. `MIX_ENV=ops iex -S mix`.

I'm assuming you're using `elixirc_paths/1` like this in your project's `mix.exs`:

```
defmodule SomeProject.Mixfile do

  use Mix.Project


  def project do
    [
      app:             :some_project,
      version:         "1.0.0",
      elixir:          "~> 1.12.3",
      elixirc_paths:   elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      ...
```

The `:elixirc_paths` option is used by the builtin `Mix` task
[`mix compile.elixir`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.Tasks.Compile.Elixir.html). [This task is
called by `mix compile`, unless you're not compiling Elixir code for your project.]

From the docs for that task [emphasis mine]:

> ### Configuration
>
> - `:elixirc_paths` - **directories** to find source files. Defaults to `["lib"]`.

Given that, if you *must* (for some reason) store a module file under `lib/`, you'd need to what
Justin Wood suggested in
[their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963493/conditional-compilation-for-a-module-inside-lib#comment88935862_50963493)
and do something like this in the module file:

```
if Mix.env() == :prod do
  defmodule SomeProject.SomeModule do
    ...
  end
end
```

Another option would be to move the module file to another top-level sub-directory of your project,
e.g. `lib_prod_only/`, and modify your `elixirc_paths/1` function:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:prod), do: ["lib", "lib_prod_only"]
defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib"]
```